# How to make a string case sensitive in python from a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have just started learning python,

I want the user input  to be case sensitive (pets list)
it only works if i only have one string in the pets variable,
how do i make it work with a list of animals ?

```
user_input=input("What animal?")
pets =('dog') #i want to add A list of animals here
if(user_input.lower() == pets):
  print ('Please feed it!')
else:print(' No need to feed '+ user_input)
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the allowed strings in a list, then use `in` to check if the lowercase input is one of the items in that list.

```
user_input=input("What animal?")
pets = ['dog', 'cat', 'hamster']
if user_input.lower() in pets:
    print('Please feed it!')
else:
    print(' No need to feed '+ user_input)
```

Also you don't have to put brackets around if-statements in python.